# Auto-Include needed C++ headers IDE?

Tags: c++, qt

I'm a Java Eclipse user as well as a Qt Creator IDE user.

In Eclipse IDE for Java, when I type this line for example :

```
Vector<int> v = new Vector<int>();
```

it automatically generate this line at the top of the code :

```
import java.util.Vector;
```

### Question :

Is there a C++ IDE or a plug-in for the Qt IDE that generates for example this line :

```
#include <vector>
```

after I type :

```
vector<int> v;
```

Comment: I don't know of one, but you have the name of the data type spelled wrong. In C++, it is vector<int>, not Vector<int>. I don't know if Vector<int> is correct in Java or not.

Comment: I love the way wclipse is doing it with Java, but C/C++ is bit sifferent and I think you better include it yourself?

Comment: I do not know any tool that does that, and you are the first one I hear asking for it. So I guess so far people would rather just include the couple of headers they need than writing and mantaining a tool that does it for them. Maybe there are correctness concerns, C++ is not that easy to parse.

Comment: @George `Vector<int>` is invalid at least up to Java 9 because you can't use primitives in generics.

Comment: Use MSVS + ReSharper

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do to automate this is going to vary by IDE. However, what you *can* do universally is Google search for say, `std::vector` and practically any result is going to include the name of the header you need.

Of course, in these days of precompiled headers, it's not unheard of to blanket `#include` a wide-range of common STL stuff even if your project doesn't currently use it.

On a related note: for your example, auto-addition is potentially ambiguous since you didn't specify the `std` namespace.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using NetBeans IDE, which can handle C/C++, PHP, Java, ....

It has autocomplete for writing functions / included headers etc.

Allso it can sometimes automatically add appropriate headers, if I use autocomplete when writing a function name, but still, it's better to define needed header files manually. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Most C++ IDEs don't provide this (though I *believe* [VisualAssist](http://www.wholetomato.com/) for Visual Studio does). As people have said, C++ is not the nicest language to parse which makes this a little more challenging.

Typically C++ folks just know what headers they need to include :)

Comment: No VisualAssist does not offer this feature.