# When should I use #include <string> directive in my program?

Tags: c++, include

I'm confused about the use of `#include <string>` directive, I know it should be used before any string is included, also too the global function `getline()`, but how when do I build and execute the following program it doesn't gave back any errors when I not included `#include <string>` directive

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    string theName;

    cout << "Enter the name: ";

    getline(cin, theName);

    cout << "The name is " << theName << endl;


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `<iostream>` *happens* to be including string for you, but that's not the case for every compiler. The principle you want to learn is "Include what you use." So, you `#include <string>` if you're using strings. It's pretty straightforward.

Comment: Depends on your compiler. `<iostream>` may include `<string>` already. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59070255/how-to-determine-which-header-files-to-include)

Comment: Probably it is already included in iostream.

Comment: `#include` statements are transitive - if header B includes header A and file C includes header B, the file C gets A as well. Standard library headers may include other headers, and this is what happens here. But it's generally a bad practice to rely on that behaviour - it makes your code very brittle. Someone may remove header A from includes in B, and suddenly file C stops compiling. Instead, always `#include` what your code uses.